# Adding Variables to .env file and getting undefiened in my front-end

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables

I'm trying to add a variable to my .env file,
so here is the steps I followed
1- I created a .env file in the root directory of the project, under the src directory
2- I added this variable

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL='lablabla'
```

3- I tried to access it from my app.tsx in the same directory (I'm using TS for the whole app)

```
 console.log("lol: ", process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL)
```

And I get undefined at my console

Things I have tried:

I tried to install dotenv and use

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

and I ran into a lot of issues, so I decided to remove it as I learned it came out of the box already with react app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> under the src directory 2- I added this variable

What do you mean by that?

Create `.env` file under root directory.
Add this content

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL='My-content'
```

In `App.jsx` get it this way

```js
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL);
```

It's important to start your env variables with prefix `REACT_APP_` and once you modify it reload the dev server.

Comment: I mean I created the .env file under the src directory (the root directory of the app)
and no it doesn't work

Comment: try outside `src` directory.

Comment: Happy to help. If you accept the answer would be nice.